# Big size array in Vivado_HLS?

Tags: vivado, vivado-hls

Is it possible to have an big size array like arr[200000] as output in top function of Vivado_HLS.

Comment: What kind of interface would you expect it to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes BUT:

- which kind of "type" are the elements of the array? `int`? `char`? a single bit?
- which kind of interface do you want to use? if you want pass all the elements at the same time, the operation may be impossible because maybe you don't have enough space on the fpga. If you are using a streaming or serial interface you can do this.

Normally you don't have this kind of limitation but you should evaluate, case by case, what is the best solution with the hardware that you have.

Answer (score 0):

The long-sized arrays are generally implemented on BRAM because the LUTS are used for small-sized arrays. So you have to consider whether you have enough resources to utilize.

If your application allows using FIFO  or axi-stream or axi-full with burst then you may think to use them to transfer the data without holding the whole array on the PL, maybe you can use a buffer that holds a small chunk of your array.
So it depends both on your board and your algorithm.